Define custom Tests in Xcode Project template
I’m working with a custom Xcode project template and want to include custom test files or implementations (eventually overrideing the default Test file templates) when adding Swift Testing or XCTest.
What modifications do I need to make to my TemplateInfo.plist to extend or override the default test templates?

This isn’t documented by Apple, making it difficult to figure out. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
